# comparing equality 2 lists resulting from entity framework query result in c#

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

My code

```
    query1 = select value1, value2 from dbo.animal where animalname="tiger";
    query2 = select value1, value2 from dbo.animal where animalname="lion";
    List<Animal> list1 = db.ExecuteStoreQuery<Animal>(query1).ToList();
    List<Animal> list2 = db.ExecuteStoreQuery<Animal>(query2).ToList();
    // list1.Count = 1 list1[0].value1 = "a" list1[0].value2 = "b"
    // list2.Count = 1 list2[0].value1 = "a" list2[0].value2 = "b"
    // Now I would like to compare list1 and list2 to see if they are equal
    var list3 = list1.Except(list2);
   //At this point list3 is containing both list1 and list2 and using var made it
 //GenericList not the same type of list as List1 and List2
```

I tried List list3 = list1.Except(list2) but I get compile error.

So the question is how do I find out if list1 is equal to list2?
I was hoping list3 would be the differences between list1 and list2 and therefore if the lists are equal list3.count() should be 0.

The nice thing about my data is I believe data in from query1 and query should be both in order and result in only 1 record each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, checking if the results of `Except` are empty cannot answer the "are these two lists equal?" question. It answers the "does `list2` contain all the elements of `list1`?", which is not the same, because `list2` *may* contain additional elements.

> The nice thing about my data is I believe data in from query1 and query should be both in order and result in only 1 record each.

You can compare two identically ordered lists for equality using `SequenceEqual`, like this:

```
bool areIdentical = list1.SequenceEqual(list2);
```

If the ordering is different, you can also force it to be the same with `OrderBy`:

```
bool areIdentical = list1
    .OrderBy(animal=>animal.Id)
    .SequenceEqual(list2.OrderBy(animal=>animal.Id));
```

Comment: That is good to know. So I used SequenceEqual and for some reason areIdentical is false when list1 and list2 have exact same animal object. Do I need to implement custom Equals method for Animal type for SequenceEqual to work?

Comment: @DoodleKana Yes, custom `GetHashCode` and `Equals` need to be there in order for the `SequenceEqual` to work properly. A good news is that if `Animal` has an `Id`, you could implement both of these methods by forwarding them to `Id`.

Comment: Awesome, I implemented both Equals and GetHashCode. When implementing Equals did seem very redundant. I wonder if there is shortcut if you meant to compare all the fields. My code looks like
public override bool Equals(Object obj){
Animal a = (Animal)obj;
if(a.name==name)&&(a.height==height)&& so on etc (20 members)
return true;
}

Comment: @DoodleKana The only shortcut I know is to use the database ID, if your `Animal` class has one. Otherwise, you're stuck with checking member-by-member equality. Of course you could drop the inner `if`, and go for `return (a.name==name)&&(a.height==height)&&...`, but this wouldn't shrink the code all that much.

Comment: Unfortunately my class does not have id. But I did take your advice on just using return with no if. For the GetHashCode I used return field1.GetHashCode()*17 + field2.GetHashCode() + etc. It seems to be working. Not sure if you have to list out every field. But sounds like if you are comparing them all you would have to use all fields. I multiplied the first field by 17 cuz I saw some example on stackoverflow someone using it as a primenumber.

Comment: @DoodleKana As far as overriding `GetHashCode` goes, although it certainly does not hurt to use all the fields, you do not have to use them all. [Here is a good answer on implementing GetHashCode](http://stackoverflow.com/a/263416/335858) when your objects have multiple fields.